# Updating JTable from a different JFrame

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe, defaulttablemodel

Actually, I have a JFrame(the main window) with a JTable in it. And couple of buttons, like Add,Delete,Refresh.

Refresh uses the function(**updateTable**) that has the following code below and works fine:

```
 try
        {
            ResultSet R = Home.getStatement().executeQuery("Select * from Schooldata");
            int count =0;
            while(R.next()) {  count++; }



school_data = new String[count][6];
            R = Home.getStatement().executeQuery("Select Schoolname,city,ProgramOpted,coordinator_name,Trainers,contactnum from Schooldata");
            count =0;
            while(R.next())
            {   
                for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
                {   school_data[count][i]= R.getString(i+1);
                    System.out.println(R.getString(i+1));
                }
                count++;
            } 
        }
        catch(SQLException S)   {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,S);}

         jTable1.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(school_data,new String [] {
                "School Name", "City", "Program", "Coordinator", "Trainers", "Contact Number"
            }));
```

When I click on "Add, another JFrame window appears and asks for Details that is further saved to Database and shows a confirmation message and refreshes the table(on a different JFrame i.e the main Window) using above function.

The Issue is, I'm calling the same function but from an another JFrame.Expecting the changes to be reflected in the main JFrame.

Using the method,**new Main().updateTable();** in the below code.It's just not working.

```
try
            {
                int confirm = Home.getStatement().executeUpdate(Query);
                if(confirm == 1)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Record Added","Saved",1);
                    new Main().updateTable();
                }
                else  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"There is some Error.....","Error",0);


            }
            catch(SQLException S)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,S,"Error",0);
            }
```

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Comment: But, actually I was doing it like, using setVisible(true) for another JFrame, and using dispose(); for the previous JFrame, Is it still not correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem *I believe* is here (it's hard to tell without a [minimal example program](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```
int confirm = Home.getStatement().executeUpdate(Query);
if(confirm == 1)
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Record Added","Saved",1);
    new Main().updateTable();  // ****** HERE ******
}
```

You're creating a completely new Main object, changing its state, and hoping that this will change the state of the visualized Main object, but you're finding out that no, it won't.

Instead you need to pass a reference of the visualized Main object into the code above, and then call methods on it, not on a newly created completely unique object.

Whatever you do, don't try solving this by making fields or methods `static`. Yes, that might work, but it breaks OOPs and makes your program difficult to test or extend.

---

As an aside, that second dependent window should not be another JFrame, and in fact likely should be a modal JDialog. For if you use a JDialog, then there would be no need for the dialog code to *push* information into the calling window. Rather the calling code will *know* when you're done dealing with the dialog, and so at this point if the dialog's state is good (if you didn't say cancel it with no changes), then the calling code can easily *pull* information from the dialog code. For a concrete example of what I"m talking about, please look at my answer to a similar question about passing information between two windows [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20454403/522444).

Also a similar problem and solution can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8524302/522444).

Comment: The OP is also creating a new instance of a JTable...have no idea whether the old ones been removed or the new one is been added +1

Comment: @MadProgrammer: thank you. Yes, an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be nice to clarify things!

Comment: Thanks, I will let you know, once I make it with JDialog.

Answer (score 0):

See weather you are disposing the main or not. If not then try creating object of Main frame and try accessing it to refresh table. You can also add import for Main Frame .java file in your refresh dialog file and  try refreshing the table. Also check if your table is public static or not so that to access it from another frame. If you create a refresh function for this purpose then it will be best. My code for function goes as -

```
    import package.mainframe;
```

or

```
    MainFrame mainframe = new MainFrame();
    try
        {
            int confirm = Home.getStatement().executeUpdate(Query);
            if(confirm == 1)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Record Added","Saved",1);
                mainframe.updateTable();    //or mainframe.functioncall();
            }
            else  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"There is some Error.....","Error",0);


        }
        catch(SQLException S)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,S,"Error",0);
        }
```

Comment: with static it works.. And the other case can be with JDialog.